# How to load GraphFrame/Pyspark DataFrame into Pytorch Geometric (InMemory)Dataset?

Tags: pyspark, pytorch, graphframes, pytorch-geometric

Anybody ever done a custom pytorch.data.InMemoryDataset for a spark GraphFrame (or rather Pyspark DataFrames? Looked for people that have done it already but didn't find anything on GitHub/Stackoverflow et cetera and I have little knowledge of pytorch geometric as of right now.
Thankful for code samples, tips or matching links :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run gcn on spark as of now. So PyTorch geometric doesn't support spark based training.